# Frequent JVM crash by SIGSEGV on cv::_OutputArray::create at libopencv_java342.so

Tags: java, opencv, jvm, contour, jvm-crash

I am getting frequent JVM crash. Using opencv with Java Imgproc library. It gets called from findContours function of Imgproc library.

> Stack: [0x00007febe3875000,0x00007febe38f6000], 
>   sp=0x00007febe38f3ea0,  free space=507k Native frames: (J=compiled
>   Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code) C 
>   [libopencv_java342.so+0x4a63f4]  cv::_OutputArray::create(int, int
>   const*, int, int, bool, int) const+0x1b4
>
> Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code) J
>   103505  org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.findContours_1(JJJII)V (0 bytes) @
>   0x00007fecec55770e [0x00007fecec5576c0+0x4e]

Fatal error :

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007febd82453f4, pid=3462, tid=0x00007febe38f5700
>
> JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_141-b15) (build 1.8.0_141-b15)
>    Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.141-b15 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
>    Problematic frame:
>    C  [libopencv_java342.so+0x4a63f4]  cv::_OutputArray::create(int, int const*, int, int, bool, int) const+0x1b4
>
> Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again

Additional details :

Tried tuning JVM memory but didn't help. Any help would be appreciated.

We are using [Imgproc JAVA library](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/imgproc.html) which usage libopencv_java342.so underneath. OS is Amazon Linux AMI VERSION="2018.03 (based on rhel fedora)

Below function of opencv is getting called from the library.

> private static native void findContours(long image_nativeObj, long
>   contours_mat_nativeObj, long hierarchy_nativeObj, int mode, int
>   method);

Comment: It might be very helpful for others if you could add some more information about the used Linux distribution, the installed libopencv library and posting a small snippet which could be used to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Added more details.

Comment: Have you figured out what the problem was?